# Which colors as background for a white logo

Tags: logo, color-theory

It is common to find white logos on a (some variant of) red background, e.g. Quora, Pinterest, Adobe, Swiss, Lego, etc. Somewhat less common is a white logo on a blue background, e.g. (Facebook) Messenger.

Why are other dark colors, like dark green or purple, not as common to use as a background for a white logo? Is it a bad idea to try out?

Answer (score 3):

The red and blue you have mentioned are usually the brand colors of the companies.

Note that, for example, Facebook's blue color came first, then later the icon was developed i.e., **f** on blue background. My point is, they don't choose color of the background just because of the logo. Reasons for choosing a brand color is not just limited to the logo.

One of the reasons for red being so common could be because it would give more attention (just like yellow) and it is often related to joy, happiness, energy.

Green is often associated with growth or health or vegetation.

But the colors are **not** limited to these characteristics only. Different cultures have different perception. Also, a lot depends on what works for the brand while advertising.

Sometimes, I feel many new startups (at least in my country) choose colors which similar brands are using. For example, if it's a food startup, they tend to use what's common/trending in food brands.

Only the company knows all reasons why they chose a specific color.

---

*Is it a bad idea to try out?*

No. There's nothing bad in green/dark green. It totally depends on your product/service and what message you want to convey. (You can easily find many famous brands with green brand color).